# JPA 2.0 reverting to JPA 1.0

Tags: jpa

Hi This Laxmi am in deep problem. with JPA Can you help me any one please.

Problem : In my project we are using JPA 2.0 and things are going done. but suddenly we need to revert to JPA 1.0 to compatibility to JBoss 5.1, then i tried to do that but iam getting an error saying No Criteria builder...then i looked into JPA 1.0 and JPA 2.0 Docs...there is no criteria api in JPA 1.0. So please help what is altenative for criteria api in JPA 1.0.

Please help me out..

Regards,
Laxmi.

Comment: Switch to another container supporting JPA 2.0 that you can deploy within JBoss. Spring for instance?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you can't use JPA 2 on JBoss 5.1?
We are using it without issues for years.
Maybe this can help:
https://community.jboss.org/thread/159628

If you still have problems I can give you some example of ours persistence.xml and (if you can tell us what DBMS you use) dbmstype-ds.xml.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Hibernate criteria.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html

Unfortunately, there are differences between those apis